# Remove/change background-color to video tag in ie html

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I have html video(using with video tag) with the dimensions width 100% and height 500px. In my width and height of browser ratio, in chrome and firefox the gap it fills with white color. But in ie, it showing black color. It looks ugly for me. I want to change or remove the background. Please give me valuable suggestion to fix this.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: If you have a fixed height, why not just set a fixed width then you won't get the extra background?

Comment: Why the html5-canvas tag ? This can be solved with CSS (`video{background:white;}`)

Comment: `video {background: white; }` doesnt work on Edge and IE.